# Faster method for creating key value pairs

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to create a mapping from key (string) to value (string[]). I read a file:

```
  gloveEmbeddings := make(map[string][]string)

  f, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./glove.840B.300d.txt")
```

The file is in the following format:

```
key0 val0_index0 val0_index1 val0_index2 val0_index3
key1 val1_index0 val1_index1 val1_index2 val1_index3
...
```

There are two separations, the new line and the space.

First I create a split of the new line:

```
newlineSplit := strings.Split(string(f), "\n")
```

Then I split each row with the space and put the first value in the resulting array as the key and the slice of the rest as the value:

```
  for i := 0; i < len(newlineSplit); i++ {
    spaceSplit := strings.Split(newlineSplit[i], " ")
    gloveEmbeddings[spaceSplit[0]] = spaceSplit[1:]
  }

  fmt.Println(gloveEmbeddings)
```

The file is 5.5GB and this loop is taking more than 20 minutes. The goal is to be able to access the value fast given the key. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT

I reading the file line by line.

```
  gloveEmbeddings := make(map[string][]string)

  f, _ := os.Open("./glove.840B.300d.txt")

  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
  count := 0
  for scanner.Scan() {
    spaceSplit := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
    gloveEmbeddings[spaceSplit[0]] = spaceSplit[1:]
    if count % 10000 == 0 {
      fmt.Println(count)
    }
    count++
  }
```

But the counts stop printing at 2.19 million.

Comment: Don't read the file in all at once. Use [`(bufio.Reader*)ReadString('\n')`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) to read it line-by-line.

Comment: Or use a [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner).

Comment: How long are those lines and how much RAM does your machine have? Even though you're now using buffering, you're still retaining all the data in memory. Do you have to do that? What do you need that map for, exactly?

Comment: I think the file contains _indices_ rather than strings, so you may want to parse the strings as `int64` or whatever as you read them. This will greatly reduce the memory impact.

Answer (score -1):

The loop actually runs fast, even the original version that uses ioutil.ReadFile. What was taking long was the fmt.Println(gloveEmbeddings) which was there only for debugging. Reading the file all at once and one line at a time take the same time, about 42-44 s on my machine.

Comment: Yes the IO operation should be the most time consuming one. Also regarding printing getting stopped after 2.19 million...it is probably because the console has exhausted its memory limit.

Comment: No that's not the reason. The reason is that there are ~2.19 million entries in the textfile, and we're printing every 10,000th iteration.